Access and refresh token management in nest js
Why when logging in through Postman it returns a refresh token and an access token, but when I log in again through Postman, it issues new refresh and access tokens?
I think it's not a good practice to issue new tokens every time. Can I use the previous unexpired refresh and access tokens on new login instead of generating new ones? Is this considered a good and secure practice?
